# Jquery mobile 1.2 landscape issue jumpy/resize before page transistion

Tags: jquery, mobile, landscape

Could someone help me please.

I'm developing a webapp with jquery mobile (1.2) and everything looks okay in portrait mode (iphone/ipad) also page transitions.

But when I turn to landscape, just before the page transition from one to the other the font size gets bigger and the view resizes.

Comment: SHow us your problem code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "initial-scale=1" in the viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

I had exact the same issue and it solved my case.